# Subscribe to YouTube channel button

Tags: youtube, youtube-api

I want to add to my site "Subscribe to channel" button which would subscribe the user who browses my site to the YouTube channel with given (fixed) ID.

How to make such a button?

Comment: What you tried to do so far? What programing language are you writing with?

Comment: @Yonlif I tried to consider copying the URL which "Subscribe" button at YouTube.com leads to. I can copy this URL so that my button would lead to the same URL, but I am not sure if it is the right thing to do. I use plain HTML and JavaScript.

Comment: Well than first write all of in your question, for your next questions please read this: [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) from the Stack Overflow Help Center.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Straight from the [source](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/code_samples/apps-script#subscribe_to_channel):

```
/**
 * This sample subscribes the active user to the GoogleDevelopers
 * YouTube channel, specified by the channelId.
 */
function addSubscription() {
  // Replace this channel ID with the channel ID you want to subscribe to
  var channelId = 'UC9gFih9rw0zNCK3ZtoKQQyA';
  var resource = {
    snippet: {
      resourceId: {
        kind: 'youtube#channel',
        channelId: channelId
      }
    }
  };

  try {
    var response = YouTube.Subscriptions.insert(resource, 'snippet');
    Logger.log(response);
  } catch (e) {
    if(e.message.match('subscriptionDuplicate')) {
      Logger.log('Cannot subscribe; already subscribed to channel: ' + channelId);
    } else {
      Logger.log('Error adding subscription: ' + e.message);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Where `YouTube` and `Logger` are defined?

Comment: This link helps you get started: https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/quickstart/js
You need an API key.

Answer (score 0):

`<a href="http://www.youtube.com/channel/UCrTPbNCktkysKMAWZKp8tBA?sub_confirmation=1">...</a>` redirects to my channel at YouTube and asks subscription confirmation.

It is exactly what I need. And this does not require API key (stroring which in a publicly accessible HTML or JavaScript file would be a big security hole).

Comment: this only works for desktop YouTube mode, no such pop up acours for mobile, which YouTube will direct you to automatically

Comment: @CaptainCrunch Please elaborate.

Comment: simply use above link on your phone's browser. you will be redirected to m.youtube.... with no "subscribe?" dialog. if you request "show desktop version" in that browser and open the link again, you'll get that dialog again. there's also a Google products discussion to that. this seems to be a new change from Google or a bug...